# Why do some components have their through-hole pins flattened/pressed near the housing?

Tags: components, pcb-assembly

Some components as depicted in the below picture have different shape in their pins.

I wonder to know is it because the manufacturer wants to tell us from where should we assemble it in the board ?

[image]

Comment: These flat strips are there because the manufacturer uses the same package for the SMD component. The pins are folded aside and cut shorter then.

Comment: It's an answer, post it like an answer.

Comment: Hi Gregory, which one? my answer or the one which Janka has replied.

Comment: @Janka good guess, but it looks like a metal case - not surface mountable without some means to isolate the case from the leads.

Comment: @stretch: The SMD package of such crystals uses the same thing as a base. To turn it into SMD, the manufacturer puts a plastic spacer below the can, then bend the pins aside.

Comment: Thanks Janka for your reply but I have seen some resistors have such a pin also, Especially those which have 1% precision

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These flat strips are there because the manufacturer uses the same package for the SMD component. To turn it into SMD, they put a plastic spacer below the can, then bend the pins aside and cut the round wire ends off.